# Hide button in css

Tags: css

How can i hide button in css it the button text is read more.

I have a add to cart button on web site product archive page. But when the product will go out of stock the check changes to read more. I want to hie the button the the text changes to read more.

Comment: can you please share html

Answer (score 10):

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="read more"/>
```

CSS

```
input[value="read more"]{ display:none; }
```

```css
input[value="read more"]{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="read more"/>

<input type="button" value="add to cart"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried its not working. This is he button class<a rel="nofollow" href="https://abc.savvatech.com/en/product/high-wall-ac-frost-4/?customize_changeset_uuid=9b219437-4ca9-412d-8193-022fb2f41061&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="289" data-product_sku="YK9FZC028BAH-AAX" class="button product_type_simple ajax_add_to_cart" target="_self">Read more</a>

Comment: I suppose if product out of stock than, it should be 0 [data-quantity="0"],  In this case you can use [data-quantity="0"] {  display:none; }

Comment: see my suggestion above

Answer (score 1):

You should use a style to rub out the button styles, but it will still keep the button text there. Apply a css class such as this to the button

```
.icon-button {
   border: none;
   background:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `display: none;` to yor button style to hide.

Comment: this will not work! display:none will hide the entire button for sure, but will also hide the text of the button, as that is part of the button!